# How to decode a base64 MEGA Link Key

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to decrypt a base64 MEGA link key, but I keep getting an exception using this code:

```
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String("MEGjPPBKkqpB_tsyqfGuvc4zUe_MRZ-GGWD4JL-89Ms");
```

the exception is *An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*, The format of s is invalid. s contains a non-base-64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space-character among the padding characters.

Comment: `_` and `-` aren't valid base64 characters... In other terms: that's not base64 encoding.

Comment: Thank you @LucasTrzesniewski , i was just trying to replicate the `base64_to_a32` method from python into C# code, in an example they worked with a key like this *OH8OnHm0VFw-9IzkYQa7VUdsjMp1G7hucXEk7QIZWvE* and it seemed to turn out fine.

Comment: Look at what I've found: `for search, replace in (('-', '+'), ('_', '/'), (',', '')):`, replacing these would yield valid base64. Note that the original code also appends the appropriate number of `=` padding characters before decoding.

Comment: Alright thank you, and now i am only stuck with the length exception which is a MEGA side error, would you please post the answer above as it answers my question ? thank you again.